# How to bind md-select(s) generated in an ng-repeat to same model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```html
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataSet | groupBy: 'partner.partnerName'"> 
  <md-select ng-model="userName"   placeholder="{{ key }}" class="partnerUser" > 
    <md-option >{{ key }} </md-option>
    <md-option ng-repeat="chatMsg in value" value="{{chatMsg.role.userId}}">{{ chatMsg.role.userId }} </md-option>
  </md-select>
</div>
```

With the above code I am generating many mdSelect directives but
I can only select one mdSelect out of many and value should be assign to model ng-model="userName".
Is there a way to bind with one mdSelect model which I can refer to later?

```html
$scope.dataSet = 
[{userName:'user1',partner :{partnerId:'1',partnerName:'firstPartner'}},
{userName:'user2',partner:{partnerId:'2',partnerName:'secondPartner'}},
{userName:'user3',partner:{partnerId:'1',partnerName:'firstPartner'}},
{userName:'user4',partner:{partnerId:'2',partnerName:'secondPartner'}
}];
```

i have a Data like this and based on partner ID record will be added to deffrent Md-select

Comment: add controller code.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign it to `value.username`.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataSet | groupBy: 'partner.partnerName'"> 
  <md-select ng-model="value.userName"   placeholder="{{ key }}" class="partnerUser" >
```

Comment: and how do i access it JS file ? like i am refering $scope.userName to get calue of userName.

Comment: @PraveenJain sorry didn't notice you used `groupBy` filter. Can you show what is the data format you expected? Because you have multiple selects with different values.

Comment: please refer or update below plunker link https://plnkr.co/edit/ufEgOLtmHpVoBmaTlrOh?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```html
<md-select ng-model="partnerDet" class="partnerUserList" placeHolder="-- Select a Partner --">
  <md-option ng-value="value[$index].partner.partnerName" data-ng-repeat="(key,value) in dataSet | groupBy: 'partner.partnerName'">{{ key }}
  </md-option>
</md-select>
```

use of $index , to bind values with variables.